# Azure storage account: general purpose vs blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Having the need to store and access blobs which type of storage account is the most appropriate? Both types (general purpose and blob storage) seem to support blobs and in addition to this general purpose accounts allow selecting default or premium performance while blob storage accounts allow only default performance but on the other hand they also allow selecting the access tier (cool or hot).

In the end I find unclear what would be the best option.

Answer (score 16):

A few differences between `Blob` and `General Purpose` Storage Accounts:

- Blob storage account only support blobs while General purpose storage accounts support blobs, files, queues & tables (some exception apply - please see note about replication below). So if you ever need these additional services, you may want to choose general purpose accounts over blob accounts.
- Blob storage account only supports block and append blobs while General purpose storage accounts support block, append & page blobs (some exception apply - please see note about replication below). So if you need to create virtual machines, you would want to choose general purpose accounts over blob accounts.
- Blob storage accounts support both `Hot` and `Cool` access tier while General purpose storage accounts only support `Hot` access tier. So if you need to use `Cool` access tier i.e. use storage primarily for near-shore archiving, you would want to choose blob accounts over general purpose accounts.

You may want to be careful in choosing replication type in general purpose accounts as features offered varies by replication types.

- LRS, GRS, RAGRS: Supports everything. Blobs (Block, Append, Page), Files, Queues & Tables.
- ZRS: Supports only block blobs and nothing else.
- Premium LRS: Supports only page blobs and nothing else.

Comment: Update as of September 2019: General Purpose Storage V2 (Gen2) supports Cool access tier, just as Blob does.

Answer (score 8):

Microsoft's guidance on this (as of 7/13/2018) recommends using `General Purpose v2` (GPv2) Storage Accounts over `Blob Storage` accounts for two reasons I recently discovered (there might be more):

1. They offer more flexibility in terms of what you can store and do with them (Queues, Tables, Files and/or Blobs vs just Blobs). Ref: [Microsoft Azure Documentation - Azure Storage account options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-options)

   > Microsoft recommends using general-purpose v2 storage accounts over Blob storage accounts for most scenarios.
2. There are more integration options with GPv2 accounts including `Azure Function` Triggers via Event Grid. Ref: [Microsoft Azure Documentation - Azure Blob storage bindings for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob#trigger)

   > Blob-only storage accounts are supported for blob input and output bindings but not for blob triggers. Blob storage triggers require a general-purpose storage account.

Answer (score 0):

Blob storage account are considered legacy, however, unlike general purpose v2, you don't have to pay an early deletion fee for Cold and Cool tier.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-overview#legacy-storage-account-types

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/access-tiers-overview#summary-of-access-tier-options

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).